# How can i get list of orders that are placed with in supplied time frame

Tags: php, api, etsy

I wanted to get list of orders that were placed/updated between given time.

I have went through the documentation but did not find any way to get list based on time, instead i can see orders has an parameter 'order_id' and 'user_id' i dont have any.

How can i get list of orders along with order details and line item details, using date range?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a reply in Etsy's Google group.
It can be done using [this](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/receipt#method_findallshopreceipts)